# variance of an autoregressive process

Tags: variance, covariance, autoregressive, asymptotic-covariance

Let $\{x_t\}_{t\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a zero mean  strictly stationary sequence of random variables and $c:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ the (auto)covariance function. If the process follows the AR(1) model
$$x_t=\rho x_{t-1}+e_t$$
with $e_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2_e)$ i.i.d. , then I read that the following holds:
$$c(0)+2\sum_{r=1}^\infty c(r)=\sigma^2\frac{1+\rho}{1-\rho}$$
**My question**

In my case, I'm dealing with the expression $c(0)+2\sum_{r=1}^\infty c(kr)$ where $k>1$ is a strictly positive natural number. Does it change the value?

**My solution** (Update)

\begin{align}
 \Big[c(0)+2\sum_{r=1}^\infty c(kr)\Big]=\sigma^2\Big(1+2\sum_{r\geq 1}\rho^{k r} \Big )=\sigma^2\frac{1+\rho^k}{1-\rho^k}
\end{align}
given that $0<\lvert \rho \rvert<1$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In time series language, you're looking at the ACF of a seasonal AR(1). The quantity you're computing is the long-run variance of a seasonal AR(1), with seasonal lag k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Then the sequence of partial sums $\{\sum_{r=1}^{a_n-1} c(kr)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence of $\{\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} c(r)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$"---this statement is not correct.

Your final result is correct. A stationary AR(1) process has autocovariance function $\gamma(r) = \rho^r$ (using more standard notation $\gamma$ instead of $c$)
When you $k$-downsampe an AR(1) process (keeping elements at multiples of $k$), the resulting process has autocovariance function $\tilde{\gamma}(r) =\gamma(kr)$. What you computed is the long run variance for the downsampled process---sum of ACF elements $\sum_r \tilde{\gamma}(r)$. Equivalently, it is the Fourier transform of $\tilde{\gamma}$ evaluated at zero frequency.

("Limiting variance" is a bit ambiguous. There is the variance of the stationary distribution $\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho^2}$ and there is the long-run variance.)

Comment: Thanks. From this result, for the MA(1) model $x_t=e_t+be_{t-1}$, we can conclude that the long-run variance is simply $\sigma^2(1+2b)$ with $\sigma^2=\sigma^2_e (1+b^2)$. This should hold since the autocovariance for lags greater than one is zero. Right?

Comment: Sorry, it's just $\sigma^2$, by hypothesis ($k>1$).